# Error: make sure cursor is initialized correctly android

Tags: android, sqlite

i have an sqliteHelper that get data from table in database,i want to build an object from this class and read database but i get that error :

> Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow,make sure cursor is initialized correctly android

this is my get function in sqliteHelper class:

```
public Vector<NoteTableItem> getAllNote() {
    Vector<NoteTableItem> list = new Vector<NoteTableItem>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + NOTE_TABLE_NAME ;

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    //startManagingCursor(c);
    c.moveToFirst();
    if (c.getCount() > 0)
    do {
     NoteTableItem item = new NoteTableItem();
     item.ID=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID));
     item.title=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE));
     item.text=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEXT));
     item.photoAddress=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHOTOADDRESS));
     item.year=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_YEAR));
     item.mounth=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MOUNTH));
     item.day=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DAY));
     item.hour=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOUR));
     item.minute=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MINUTE));
     item.checked=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHECKED));
     list.add(item);
    } while (c.moveToNext());
    db.close();
    return list;
   }
```

i just want to create an object of this class.

```
private static final String CREATE_NOTE_TABLE_NAME = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
+ NOTE_TABLE_NAME
+ "("
+ KEY_ID 
+ " INTEGER   , "
+ KEY_TITLE 
+ " TEXT   , "
+ KEY_TEXT 
+ " TEXT   , "
+ KEY_PHOTOADDRESS 
+ " TEXT   , "
+ KEY_YEAR 
+ " INTEGER   , "
+ KEY_MOUNTH 
+ " INTEGER   , "
+ KEY_DAY 
+ " INTEGER   , "
+ KEY_HOUR 
+ " INTEGER   , "
+ KEY_MINUTE 
+ " INTEGER   , "
+ KEY_CHECKED 
+ " INTEGER   ) ; ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor doesn't contain all the columns you think and `getColumnIndex()` returns `-1` to indicate "not found" for at least one of the columns.

If you believe the columns should be there, uninstall your app to get rid of a possible old database file.

Comment: Post the db schema (the `CREATE TABLE`) if you need help figuring it out.

Comment: i could work with this code already, but now this is not work!!

Comment: i undrestand my mistake,i edited table notetableitem but does not clear old table :-)